# Borrar elementos de una lista anidada

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

```
calendario = calendar.monthcalendar(año, mes);

for i in range(len(notrabajo)-1):
  for indice in range(len(calendario[valor])):

    if calendario[valor][indice] == notrabajo[i]:

      calendario.pop(indice)

    valor += 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes tener cuidado con eliminar objeto de un iterable mientras iteras sobre él para evitar invalidar el iterador o generar índices inválidos. En tu caso podrías simplemente romper el ciclo anidado una vez que encuentras el día ya que solo realizas una eliminación por vuelta del primer ciclo.

No obstante, puedes simplificarlo usando solo un ciclo y `list.remove`:

```
import calendar


año = 2020
mes = 4
calendario = calendar.monthcalendar(año, mes)
notrabajo = [5, 12, 11, 19]

for dia in notrabajo:
    for semana in calendario:
        try:
            semana.remove(dia)
        except ValueError:
            continue
```